# Spring Boot JPA - Randomised Pagination

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

I have an API endpoint to return a list of `Community`. I currently return a paginated response, using the JPA `Page` class, as demonstrated below. How can I randomise the order in which rows are retrieved? I have attempted to use an `ORDER BY RAND()` in the JPA query, however this results in repeated results on different pages (e.g. `id` 1 is on pages 3,5,7).

Repository:

```java
@Query(
            value = "SELECT c FROM Community c LEFT JOIN FETCH c.logo log " +
                    "LEFT JOIN FETCH c.banner ban LEFT JOIN FETCH c.background bg " +
                    "LEFT JOIN FETCH c.tags " +
                    "WHERE c.name LIKE %:name% AND c.abbreviation LIKE %:abbreviation% ORDER BY RAND()",
            countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(c) FROM Community c WHERE c.name LIKE %:name% AND c.abbreviation LIKE %:abbreviation%"
    )
    Page<Community> findAllWithTagsWithLogoWithBannerByIdNotNull(Pageable pageable, @Param("name") String name, @Param("abbreviation") String abbreviation);
```

Service Layer:

```java
public Page<Community> listSocialCommunities(Integer page, Integer size, String name, String abbreviation) {
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, size);
        return communityRepository.findAllWithTagsWithLogoWithBannerByIdNotNull(pageable, name, abbreviation);
    }
```

DB: MySQL 8

Java 17

Any suggestions welcomed.

Comment: You want random ordering but not repeated results in paging, that seems to be conflicting.

Comment: Not really. I want the order of results to be random, but I don't want individual communities to appear more than once

Comment: Consistent but random ordering between different queries simply isn't going to happen unless you save that order somewhere. So either make a single query then retrieve pages in batches, or somehow save that random order somewhere. Perhaps in a temporary view?

Comment: Ugh, was hoping there might be an easier way to do it... Alright thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate on the use-case, this seems quite strange (is this a school project?)

Comment: It's not a school project. It's a directory of gaming communities on a website, and we want to randomise the return order, as to give everyone a chance of being on the first page of results